# Why JQUERY clone functions and appending an id to it and confirm email value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

I am having 2 tricky UX JQuery problems that I'm currently working on.
I am cloning a 2 form variables using JQuery. How do I index, id them so I can label them with this id. 
For example if I pick 3 from the select box I should get 3 lines of form and on the left hand side of each line should begins with a number starting 1. form, 2. form, 3 form.

The second problem I have I want to validate attendant[] against confirmattendant[]. How would I do this inside a cloned HTML code.

Here is my JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tGprH/5/

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<p>Email address, Confirm Email Address</p>
#1 <input type="text" name="attendant[]"/>
<input type="text" name="confirmattendant[]"/>
<br/>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$("select").change(function() {

    var select = parseInt($('#select').val() , 10);
    var $clone = '<input type="text" name="attendant[]" /><input type="text" name="confirmattendant[]" /><br/>';
    console.log($clone);
    var html = '';
    for(var i = 1;i< select ; i++){
        html += $clone;
    }
    $('#container').empty().html(html);
 }).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print the required in your for loop like..

```
html += '#'+(i + 1)+ ' '+$clone;
```

try this

```
$("select").change(function() {

   var select = parseInt($('#select').val() , 10);
   var $clone = '<input type="text" name="attendant[]" /><input type="text" name="confirmattendant[]" /><br/>';
   console.log($clone);
   var html = '';
   for(var i = 1;i< select ; i++){
      html += '#'+(i + 1)+ ' '+$clone;
   }
   $('#container').empty().html(html);
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/tGprH/6/)

Answer (score 0):

About the first problem : http://jsfiddle.net/tGprH/7/

```
$("select").change(function() {

    var select = parseInt($('#select').val() , 10);
    var $clone = '<input type="text" name="attendant[]" /><input type="text" name="confirmattendant[]" /><br/>';
    console.log($clone);
    var html = '';
    for(var i = 1;i< select ; i++){
        if(i >= 1)
            html +=  '#' + (i+1) + ' ' + $clone;
        else
            html += $clone;
    }
    $('#container').empty().html(html);
 }).change();
```

And about the comparison : http://jsfiddle.net/tGprH/8/

```
<button id="compare">compare</button>

$('#compare').click(function(){
   var $attendantArray =  $('input[name="attendant[]"]');
   var $confirmattendantArray =  $('input[name="confirmattendant[]"]');
   for(var i = 0;i< $attendantArray.length ; i++)
   {
       alert((i+1) + ' attendant [' + $($attendantArray[i]).val() + ' / ' + $($confirmattendantArray[i]).val() + ']')
   }
});
```